# Items Don't Stay Where Placed With Drag Drop Feature in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, drag-and-drop, emulation

So Android Studio has the drag/drop feature in the design tab. I am able to place the elements where I want them, and the layout looks great on the screen.

However, when I go to run the app emulator, it looks completely different. Everything gets shoved up to the top-left hand corner of the screen, nowhere near where I placed it in design mode.

Is there a way to have your elements show the same way in the emulator, as the way you place them in design mode? Right now I'm having to go back and edit all the code each time.

I have my code below, as well as a image link below to further clarify my point.[Comparison of Design mode vs App Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uOSl.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.luke.currencyconverter.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter The Amount in Dollars"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-159dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="126dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="403dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Enter The Amount in Dollars:"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="33dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="365dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/currency"
        android:layout_width="361dp"
        android:layout_height="450dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/currency"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="12dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-117dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/convert"
        android:layout_width="361dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="convert"
        android:text="Convert"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="12dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="462dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/dollarField"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="408dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Drag and drop not recommended.

Comment: You should post your code.

Comment: use a linearlayout drag and drop works only by settings constraints or different devices have different screen size and may not work as you expect to do.

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop for android will only place the object within the screen. To keep it there you should modify the xml so that the objects will be constrained to each other.

You can use either relative layout or constraint layout for an easier time in designing your layout.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was using "constraint layout", and I needed to use "relative layout".

Answer (score 0):

I just had this error as well and as annoying as it sounds, my solution was to delete my xml file and recreate it.